# DocumentDb Id field

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is there a data type or length restriction to DocumentDb Id fields?

I've been using GUID values in the ID field in my DocumentDb database and everything has been working fine.

I now need to make a change in the ID field and add a prefix to the IDs. This is not yet running on production. I'm just testing it locally using the DocumentDb emulator.

Just to give you an example, my Id used to be a typical GUID like this: `5e035f00-e1e3-430d-ae45-85f2815731f7`. Now, it will be something like this: `20-5e035f00-e1e3-430d-ae45-85f2815731f7`. Basically, I'm adding a 2-4 digit prefix followed by a hyphen to the beginning of Id's now.

Looks like I'm able to create the documents fine but when it comes to querying them, I'm getting an error in my code. I did not make any changes to the code that runs queries against the database.

Here's the query code that's been running all along:

```
public async static Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
   {
      var docQuery = query.AsDocumentQuery();
      var batches = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();

      do
      {
         var batch = await docQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>(); // My code is blowing up here
         batches.Add(batch);
      }
      while (docQuery.HasMoreResults);

      var docs = batches.SelectMany(b => b);

      return docs;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit for practical purpose. Can you post the callstack for your "blowing up" place?

Comment: Thanks for the verification. It was my fault. I forgot to change the data type of the ID field from GUID to string in one of my objects. I wasn't getting a visible error so I didn't know what the issue was but further examination showed that it was the data type for the ID field. Thanks again.